# Sane can't see Samsung CLX-3305W network scanner in Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: networking, scanner, sane

I've installed a new Samsung CLX-3305W multifunction printer/scanner a couple of weeks ago on a dual boot system with W7 on one physical drive and Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit on a separate drive.

The printer is connected via LAN, through a router and used as a network printer/scanner. Windows has no problems printing and scanning over the network however, Ubuntu will only print and won't see/recognize the scanner. I've been prowling relevant Linux forums for advice and a solution, but to date nothing worked.

Ubuntu is updated and as far as I can tell, all relevant drivers are present together with sane-utils, libsane and libsane-extras. I also have Simple Scan and Xsane installed. I can get around this problem by scanning directly to a USB memory stick or booting into Windows every time I need to scan something, but not being able to scan directly to Ubuntu is driving me silly. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: changes has to be done in dll.conf and to append the model number in config file. Please refer the following link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SANE%20-%20Installing%20a%20scanner%20that%20isn%27t%20auto-detected

Comment: Thanks for responding. The scanner has backend support via xerox.mfp. The vendor id in xerox_mfp.conf is correct and since this is a network scanner connected via ethernet as opposed to USB, I've also added the line "tcp 192.168.0.xxx:9100, but sane is still unable to find the scanner.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps.

```
echo -e "\nblacklist usblp" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

I have samsung-scx4200 and this helps to me.

https://extremeshok.com/6138/ultimate-raspberry-pi-lan-print-scan-and-pdf-server-cups-airprint-ipp-cups-pdf-sanescan-sanetwain-phpsane-scanner-webinterface-samba-remote-file-access/

Comment: Many thanks for trying to help. I've checked blacklist.conf and usblp was indeed blacklisted so I commented it out, but it didn't fix the problem. Also, the printer is connected via ethernet (LAN) and not USB so I'm not sure if this made any difference in my case. Thanks again.